# Are there any finite dimensional associative and commutative algebras which are reduced, but not semisimple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In other words, I am looking for a finite dimensional associative and commutative algebra with non-trivial Jacobson radical, but trivial nilradical. Does such a finite dimensional associative and commutative algebra exist?

Comment: What "nilradical" do you mean? Are you talking about commutative rings after ajll?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I forgot to put commutative in my original post, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A finite dimensional algebra will be Artinian, and the prime ideals must be maximal.

Therefore the Jacobson and nilradicals coincide.